# Call function on pointer in same statement as nullptr pointer check?

Tags: c++, pointers

In C++, if you have a pointer type and want to do a `nullptr` check to make sure that the pointer is valid, is it safe to include other checks in the same `if` statement that include the pointer that is being checked?

For example:

```
Control* c = nullptr;
if (c && c->is_view())
{
    // do stuff
}
```

The pointer `c` is being checked to see if it is `nullptr`, but in the same conditional statement the `is_view()` function is being called on the `c` pointer. The call to `is_view()` assumes that the pointer is valid.

Is this code safe?

Comment: `&&` can be overloaded, but it doesnt matter here. It might if the expression was `foo && c && c->is_view()`

Comment: fwiw, "valid pointer" != "not a nullptr". You can use smart pointers if you want to be able to check if a pointer is valid or not.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number `operator&&` can be overloaded only for custom class/struct types, not for built-in types, including pointers. Also, smart pointers merely manage the lifetime of an object, you can't use a smart pointer to just "check if a pointer is valid". It is possible for a smart pointer to hold an invalid pointer, if you are not careful with it.

Comment: A null pointer is not a valid pointer.  But on the flipside, a non-null pointer is not **necessarily** a valid pointer, because it could be a dangling pointer, or a "valid pointer that cannot be dereferenced because it does not point to a valid object, because it is *one-past*" (which has a small set of use cases), or a wild pointer, or an uninitialized pointer.  (It was pointed out to me, correctly, that my terminology here is *jargon*, and not **normative**.)

Comment: @RemyLebeau what I said. It does not matter for this specific case, but with `custom_foo && c && c->is_view` it might matter.